# Intento hacer una condición en un query en laravel pero no logro dar con la solución final

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

El query que hago es este:

```
Turnos::where('id', '', $req->id)
      ->where(DB::raw("('hora_inicio' between '".$req->inicio."' and '".$req->fin."' or 'hora_final' between '".$req->inicio."' and '".$req->fin."')"))
      ->exists();
```

El sql que me retorna esto, ejemplo, es el siguiente:

```
select * from "turnos" where "id" <> '5' and ('hora_inicio' between '06:00' and '11:59' or 'hora_final' between '06:00' and '11:59')
```

El sql que intento hacer es:

```
select * from "turnos" where "id" <> '5' and ("hora_inicio" between '06:00' and '11:59' or "hora_final" between '06:00' and '11:59')
```

El problema esta en las comillas de la columna.

**NOTA:**

aclaro que la condición del id es "<>" no lo refleja el modo código de la web.

**Actualización 1:**

Realizo la consulta como lo hiciste en la respuesta que me diste, ¿Por que me agrega un `is null` dentro del where? Ojo la consulta la acomode moviendo asi el `between`.

```
Turnos::where('id', '', $id)
     ->where(DB::raw("'".$inicio."' between hora_inicio and hora_final or '".$fin."' between hora_inicio and hora_final"))
     ->exists();
```

Sql resultante:

```
select exists(select * from "turnos" where "id"  '6' and '00:00' between hora_inicio and hora_final or '10:59' between hora_inicio and hora_final is null) as "exists"
```

Comment: Porqué le pones comillas a los nombres de las columnas? No funciona sin las comillas?

Comment: @jemonje seguramente las comillas las agrega Eloquent. @pablocontreras, yo no veo diferencia entre las últimas dos sentencias que pusiste, pero sí veo que te falta un operador entre `id` y `'5'`

Comment: el problema esta en las comillas simples y dobles.. el script requiere de comillas dobles para interpretarlo como una columna, y si es comilas simples lo interpreta como un string @amenadiel

Comment: @amenadiel y coloque en la nota al final de la pregunta que el operador lo tiene que el modo codigo de la web no lo reconoce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que simplemente tienes que omitir las comillas en tu consulta raw

```
Turnos::where('id', '', $req->id)
      ->where(DB::raw("(hora_inicio between '".$req->inicio."' and '".$req->fin."' or hora_final between '".$req->inicio."' and '".$req->fin."')"))
      ->exists();
```

Comment: :V matenme por favor, la solución era tan obvia y no la veía, gracias hermano.

Comment: Modifique la pregunta y solo me queda una duda por aclarar y es ¿Por que me agrega un "is null" al final del "where"?

Comment: Creo que no va a funcionar el uso de `where  $valor between campo1 and campo2` sino que siempre tiene que ser de la forma `where campo1 between $valor1 and $valor2`. En este caso el orden de los factores sí altera el producto

Comment: da el resultado que queria solo es el "is null" que se agrega ahora

Comment: Yo creo que por omisión está interpretando el último `and hora_final` como `and hora_final is null`. A lo mejor encontraste un bug en el parser de Eloquent

Comment: y lo que me quieres decir es que no hay solución, ¿cierto?

Comment: Tal vez volviendo a la query que tenías al principio, pero sin entrecomillar los nombres de los campos

Comment: no da el resultado que necesito, si soluciona la pregunta que consulta efectivamente las columnas correctamente, pero no es el query que realmente necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar el is null del final debes usar el método whereRaw();

```
Turnos::where('id', '', $req->id)
      ->whereRaw("(hora_inicio between '".$req->inicio."' and '".$req->fin."' or hora_final between '".$req->inicio."' and '".$req->fin."')")
      ->exists();
```

El metodo where() es el que te agrega el is null. Ya que espera poner campo = valor.
En tu caso campo es el DB::raw y los otros dos valores deben ser los valores por defecto.